# How to search with case sensitive with ag in MAC?

Tags: ag

i want to search with case sensitive, seems "ag -i" should do the job.
But when i run it in MAC, seems it's not the case.

Anyone has same issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ag -s pattern

this works in MAC.